# How to add watermark to PDF file with PHP and FPDI for Print only?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, watermark, fpdi

I am using FPDF and FPDI to add current date to the existing PDF file

`$pdf->Cell(0,15, date("Y/m/d"), 0, 0,'R' );`

Is it possible to make it visible only when document is printed, something like Set Visibility Print Only?

(Sorry if duplicate, I'm new here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the script "[Visibility](http://fpdf.org/en/script/script75.php)" from the script section of FPDF for this purpose. Just change the class so that it extends FPDI:

```
class PDF_Visibility extends \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi 
{ ...
```

You should know that this does not work for all PDF readers/viewers. Viewers not supporting visibility will show the content throughout.

Comment: Tried that and got Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDF::SetVisibility() (added require('visibility.php') to my script and changed class in visibility script)

Comment: Then you do not inherit the classes correctly or initiate a wrong class. As I do not know your code, this is sadly out of my scope. Just double check that you require and initiate the correct class. Maybe [this](http://fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php#q13) may help you, too.

Comment: I found the mistake, I forgot to change $pdf = new PDF(); to $pdf = new PDF_Visibility(); now it works, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome to accept my answer then, thanks ;-)